# Why do I get this error trying to run this VUE JS repository?

Tags: vue.js

> This is a VUE JS MASONRY project on the GitHub.  I just trying to run
>   it. I've already run the npm install before run it.  It seems like the
>   all the packages  have been installed properly.
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vue-masonry-plugin-demo-master>npm start
>
> ```
>         > vue-masonry-demo@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vue-masonry-plugin-demo-master
>         > node build/dev-server.js
>
>         > Starting dev server...
>         events.js:187
>               throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>
>         Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
>             at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1300:14)
>             at listenInCluster (net.js:1348:12)
>             at Server.listen (net.js:1436:7)
>             at Function.listen (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vue-masonry-plugin-demo-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
>             at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vue-masonry-plugin-demo-master\build\dev-server.js:83:18)
>             at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
>             at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
>             at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
>             at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
>             at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
>             at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
>         Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
>             at emitErrorNT (net.js:1327:8)
>             at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
>           code: 'EADDRINUSE',
>           errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
>           syscall: 'listen',
>           address: '::',
>           port: 8080
>         }
>     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>     npm ERR! errno 1
>     npm ERR! vue-masonry-demo@1.0.0 start: `node build/dev-server.js`
>     npm ERR! Exit status 1
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the vue-masonry-demo@1.0.0 start script.
>     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
>     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-05T22_23_37_278Z-debug.log
>     PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vue-masonry-plugin-demo-master>
> ```
>
> PACKAGE.JSON
>
> {   "name": "vue-masonry-demo",   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "A Vue.js project",   "author": "Mikhail Kuznetcov
>   ",   "private": true,   "scripts": {
>       "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
>       "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
>       "build": "node build/build.js"   },

Comment: This is the important bit: `address already in use :::8080`. You already have a server running on port 8080. If it isn't obvious what it is try accessing it using a web browser, or use `netstat` to track down the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
```

If you check it here, you will figure it out.